# It it possible to define a state that transitions to itself in xstate?

Tags: state, state-management, xstate

Consider the following FSM:

```js
{
  id: 'my_machine',
  initial: 'foo',
  states: {
    foo: {
      on: { 
        TRIGGER_BAR: 'bar'
      }
    },
    bar: {
      on: {
        TRIGGER_BAR: 'bar'
        TRIGGER_FOO: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible for `bar` to transition to `bar` again via the `TRIGGER_BAR` event?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! These are called self transitions.

> A self-transition is when a state transitions to itself, in which it may exit and then reenter itself. Self-transitions can either be an internal or external transition.

By default all self-transitions are external, so they will exit and re-enter again. Read the [docs](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#self-transitions) to see how to change this.

In the example above, you probably wouldn't want to transition to `bar` again, since there is no context value update. But you could very well have an action created with [assign](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/context.html#assign-action) that mutates the context.